# How do I give imageNameRegex an actual regular expression

Tags: java, regex, amazon-ec2, jclouds, brooklyn

I'm trying to use a specific AMI on AWS using it's name.

It works if I set `imageNameRegex = region/image_name` but fails if I try any of the following:

```
imageNameRegex = image_name
imageNameRegex = .*/image_name
imageNameRegex = .*image_name
imageNameRegex = /.*image_name/
```

The aim here is that I can copy an AMI across a number of regions and have Brooklyn pick up the correct one without my having to specify a specific image id for that region.

Looking at the Brooklyn tests then I shouldn't even need a regex - as long as the name is a substring of the full name it should work.

I'm setting this in the `brooklyn.properties` not the yaml all though I can't imagine that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also need to specify the image owner.

As I recall, jclouds does something a little surprising with image owners: if you specify an image name regex, it will only look in a small number of image owner (rather than across all 20,000+ images, which can take 60+ seconds to retrieve from AWS on some home networks).

If you specify the image owner, then it should find it, such as:

```
imageOwner = 411009282317
```

You can also set the `anyOwner` location configuration, but this will check *every* AMI it can find:

```
anyOwner = true
```

Answer (score 1):

jclouds restricts the number of owners being queried to the more common ones to have better response times. However, if you want to have a more open query, you can override the default one by setting the `jclouds.ec2.ami-query` property when creating the context. By default, jclouds uses this one:

`owner-id=137112412989,801119661308,063491364108,099720109477,411009282317;state=available;image-type=machine`

Comment: I don't think we support the `jclouds.ec2.ami-query` property in Brooklyn, so you have to search in one specific owner by setting the `imageOwner` flag on the location.